# SQL ZOO SELECTT WITIHIN SELECT TUORIAL 5

Tags: sql

Germany (population 80 million) has the largest population of the countries in Europe. Austria (population 8.5 million) has 11% of the population of Germany.

Show the name and the population of each country in Europe. Show the population as a percentage of the population of Germany.

The format should be Name, Percentage for example:

```
name    percentage
Albania 3%
Andorra 0%
Austria 11%
```

My Answer is

```
SELECT name,Concat(ROUND(population*100/(select population from world where name = 'Germany'),0),'%')
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe'

name    percentage
Albania 3.000000000000%
Andorra 0.000000000000%
Austria 11.000000000000%
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: It is the "Percentages of Germany" task on SqlZoo: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial#Percentages_of_Germany

Answer (score 1):

Try `CAST` it

```
SELECT name, CONCAT(CAST(ROUND(population * 100/(select population from world where name = 'Germany'),0) AS INT),'%')
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit strange, but the following SQL works on SqlZoo:

```
select name,
       concat(cast (round(100 * population / (select population from world where name = 'Germany'), 0) as int), '%')
  from world
 where continent = 'Europe'
```

First you have to cast the result to int and concat the % sign to it.